# Exchange of Fluorine to Oxygen for Fluorophosphonic acid by silylating agents or other methods?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, synthesis, purification, organophosphorus-compounds

[Warning, long post!]

Dear all,

I am confronted with a seemingly easy transformation. I want to remove a fluorine atom at a fluor phosphonic acid salt. The usual method to achieve this is the basic hydrolysis or the hydrolysis with acid. These methods are not applicable here.

See also:  *The Hydrolysis of Phosphinates and Phosphonates: A Review*  https://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/26/10/2840

1. Base will not hydrolyze the compound, because it is shielded from nucleophilic attack.
2. Acid will deteriorate the compound and is also not applicable.
3. I recently tried to achieve hydrolysis by TMSBr cleavage. I see the intended mass in LCMS, but the compound is likely to be contaminated by other polar species. Also, during the workup traces of acids may emerge.
   I did the reaction with TMSBr at 60 degrees. Maybe other conditions would lead to a different outcome, but this is not explored yet.

[image]

Because these reactions are neither robust nor is the outcome easily quantified in terms of yield and purity, I tried the attachment of a cleavage group like benzyl, that does not require acidic or basic conditions.

[image]

This route works nicely in theory, but in reality, I see almost no product. The concept is elegant, but performing 3 reactions to get the final product will lead to a major loss of the final product.

Therefore I still have not a way to get the structure I want yet in a robust fashion. Waylander from this board recommended the use of Siylating agents as a temporary cleaving group and the concept I find to be interesting.

[image]

I already observed with other esters, that in the moment the negative charge is neutralized, the fluorine will leave the molecule eagerly. The advantage here is definitely, that a TMS-Ester may also be applicable for easy cleavage, even after the fluorine left the molecule. I did not have the opportunity to test this strategy yet, but I am a little bit concerned, that the -OTMS will be cleaved before the fluorine leaves, leaving me right where I began. However, I did further research on the topic, and I found some interesting reactions where fluorine itself will act as a leaving group.

[image]

If I receive the double TMS ester, I would have an easy time, because this would go easily in the organic phase in aq/DCM workup and could be easily purified from any excess fluoride and inorganic byproducts and then could be hydrolyzed with water to the salt in the next step under basic conditions with ammonia.

[image]

Do you think double silylating is applicable? Would it be feasible to use for example a mixture of diethylaminotrimethylsilane and  Hexamethyldisiloxan (for the second silylation step)? I don't care what the intermediate is, as long as everything can be cleanly hydrolyzed to the free phosphonate salt. The reagents themselves must not introduce acid into the system when in contact with water and all byproducts must be volatile.
I found a lot of different silayting agents here, https://technical.gelest.com/brochures/silicon-based-blocking-agents/general-silylation-procedures, but I am not experienced with the usage of such chemicals with individual pros and cons.

Comment: I tried today to silyate my compound in excess with HMDS unter reflux conditions. In LCMS I did not find the TMS-Ester or the free phosphonic acid. I guess it might be possible that the TMS-ester, if it had been formed, just  immediately hydrolyses during the analytic run at pH 2.8 for 11 min. I will try Si NMR, I would assume that from my starting material I will only observe one other SI signal and will also do an NMR of HMDS for reference.

Comment: I fully believe it @raptorlane

Comment: What do you believe? 

Comment: I think the silylation strategy is interesting, but HMDSO is not a strong silylating agent, so I don't think you'd get your desired fluoride elimination in the last scheme. Have you considered using potassium trimethylsilanolate (KOTMS)? I'm not fully convinced when you say SN2 can't be done due to shielding, because phosphorus is big. You could just be deactivating it from nucleophilic attack after deprotonation. If you silylate the OH/O- and then heat with KOTMS in, say, THF or dioxane or MeCN, you might displace the fluoride and crash out KF.

Comment: Another possible silylating agent to consider is hexamethyldisilazane (HMDS). You'd think it might end up making a phosphoramide, but for some reason the ammonia byproduct it generates does not seem to participate in further reactions. It's possible that HMDS plus a catalytic acid like TMSCl/TMSBr or saccharin may trigger the fluoride to leave, but I can't immediately think of how to best leverage it, because you'd need to add a nucleophile to the medium which either ends in your product or is easier to remove later. Maybe chloride/bromide already fits the bill? And workup is just rotovap.

Comment: Regarding the substitution of the fluorine: This is more optional and not my primary goal. In the moment the silylether is formed, the fluorine is likely to go off relatively easyl. I read that TMS is normally deprotected with MeOH and K2CO3 (pH 12) while the Fluor in Sarin for example will leave quite fast at pH 9. When this is true, one could achieve a sequential hydrolysis. However, the TMS ester was not observed after refluxing with HMDS, I did columns runs via LCMS as direct injection, so that the compound is only exposed a couple of seconds to the acidic mobile phase.

Comment: However, I did not observe the suspected masses. Maybe the compound does not tolerate reflux conditions, an alternative route would be to use TMSEDA at RT for couple of hours.

Comment: Indeed, the phosphonic TMS ester is likely extremely sensitive to hydrolysis. I have experience with carboxylic TMS esters (which should be more stable than phosphoric TMS esters) and simply dissolving the pure COOTMS ester in CDCl3 (stored over basic alumina to remove free acid/phosgene) and transferring the solution in air to an NMR tube over the course of ~15 s lead to ~5% desilylation by 1H NMR, presumably from trace moisture. It could be helpful if you run reaction tests in deuterated solvents and do NMR vial reactions, checking the progress directly by 1H and 19F NMR.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152340/discussion-between-nicolau-saker-neto-and-raptorlane).